# String equals giving odd results

Tags: java, string, if-statement, equality

I am fairly new to java, and I cannot figure out for the life of me why this piece of code is not working, I am trying to see if a word is an adverb, and hence if it ends in "ly" or not (they will always be lowercase).
This is my code:

```
    String str = "evenly";
    int a = str.length()-2;
    int b = str.length();
    String res = (String)str.substring(str.length()-2,str.length());
    System.out.println(res + " == ly -> " + (res == "ly"));
```

I am testing it here: http://ideone.com/4FuBwj
The output is: `ly == ly -> false`
Which means that, `res = "ly"` but `res == "ly"` is `false`?
Why is this happening?

Comment: Don't compare Strings with ==. Use the `res.equals()` method. `(res.equals("ly"))`

Comment: Tip: Add @Kon (the `@` is important) or whoever, to *notify* them of a new comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Kon has stated in the comments, you shouldn't be comparing the Strings with the == operation, it should be done with the String.equals() method. You could possibly even use the String.equalsIgnoreCase() method if you're wanting to ignore case sensitivity between the values.

```
System.out.println(res + " == ly -> " + (res.equals("ly")));
```

or as above

```
System.out.println(res + " == ly -> " + (res.equalsIgnoreCase("ly")));
```

Hope this helps!